# Stuck at 11 minutes remaning while installing macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra

had some issues with my mac which forced me to factory reset it but now i am stuck at installation and its not moving forward. It says "11 Minutes Remaining" and its just stuck there, I am leving it as it is and will be sleeping now, hoping when i wake up it would have co.pleted the process, if not please give me some solution to what i can do next?

[image]

Comment: What Apple device is this? I am wondering why the disk is named "Untitled". Is this a laptop? Mac Mini? iMac? What year model? tell us more about your computer, because it may be a compatibility issue with High Sierra or something like that.

Comment: It is Macbook Pro 15" mid12015 model, the reason disk is showing untitled is because i formatted it with that name. My laptop already had High Sierra installed but because of some issues i was forced to factory reset my laptop, so I went into recovery mode, formatted my laptop in APFS format and tried to install macOS, When I got stuck here.